# Listening to observable events inside items in a list

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I've got an `IObservable<ImmutableArray<T>>` where each `T` has a corresponding Delete command, an `IObservable<Unit>`. I'm trying to respond when the user clicks Delete on an item in the list. When an item is added to the list, I want to start listening (subscribe) for the Delete command. When an item is removed from the list I want to stop listening (unsubscribe). If an item X is added to the list and the list changes many times, I want to ensure I've only subscribed to the Delete command on X once - when it was added - rather than unsubscribe and resubscribe every time the list changes.

Originally I tried to do this using the `Switch` command. But then I realized that it probably is unsubscribing and resubscribing to each item every time the list changes. This makes it difficult to use Pairwise or Scan since every time the list changes my subscription gets wiped out and I start with a new one. I think I ran into other problems with it, but it generally it doesn't seem like the right answer with all those subscribes and unsubscribes.

So I think the answer involves using `TakeUntil`. I'll monitor the list, do a Pairwise on it, and be able to always know what is New and Removed. Then when I subscribe to each item, I'll do a `TakeUntil` that item is in the Removed set. Well that is the idea but I'm having trouble with the code.

This is what I'm working with:

```
interface IListItem {
    IObservable<Unit> Delete { get; }
    string ListItemName { get; }
}

IObservable<ImmutableList<IListItem>> _list;

_list...something here...Subscribe(i=>{
    Console.WriteLine($"You requested to delete {i}!");
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you have an `ImmutableList` in `IObservable<ImmutableList<IListItem>>`, and not just `IObservable<IListItem>`?

Comment: It seems to me that if you are pushing the entire current list across for each value of the observable that you just need to see if the item is now absent from those previously pushed across - no need for a `IObservable<Unit> Delete` to know when the item is deleted. Can you help explain?

Comment: Each item in the list is a view model with commands like Edit, MoveUp, MoveDown, and Delete - the Delete one is confusing you. I want to know when the user clicks MoveDown on any particular item in the list. The list is frequently changing as the user adds and remove items, and I want to only listen for events that pertain to items currently in the list.

Comment: The "Delete" one isn't confusing me - it's the combination of the `ImmutableList` and the "Delete" one. You haven't answered my second comment.

Comment: I have a IObservable<ImmutableList<T>> for items I get from a database. I convert this to ImmutableList<TViewModel>, making sure to create new view models for newly added items and disposing ones that have gone away. I synchronize that ImmutableList<TViewModel> with a ReadOnlyObservableCollection for UI data binding. Each view model might have a ICommand MoveUp, exposed internally to the view model as IObservable<Unit>. So how do I listen to all the IObservable<Unit> within the list, but stop subscribing when an item is removed from the list?

Comment: As view model items are built, I could wire up the commands on each item so when the user invokes them, they could publish through a single Subject owned by the parent view model, something like `IObservable<Guid> MoveUpRequest`. Then I just listen to that one observable to know which Guid is supposed to be moved up. I think I like the way I do it though since the items in the list don't have any kind of dependency on anything else.

Comment: Do you always have a corresponding "Delete" when you also remove the item from the list?

Comment: When the user invokes Delete, I might update the database and then pull down a whole new set of data for the list (local SqlLite). I think this is like React one-way data flow. I don't delete key x from the database and then manually also delete key x from my in memory list. Another way to do this is to wire up the command on each list item view model to actually call the Delete function, so I'm not listening for it. I think I prefer keeping the list item completely unaware of its context.

Comment: So in other words, the list itself is managed from the database and you only get `IObservable<Unit> Delete` when a user clicks delete?

Comment: Yes something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think I got a decent answer here. A bit longer that I'd like but I think it works. If anyone wants to suggest something shorter or simpler, I'd love to hear it. The part `.Select(add => add.Delete.Select(_ => add).TakeUntil...` is weird. Basically when the delete command is invoked for a specific list item, I want to return the list item that the Delete command was invoked on.

```
_items
.Pairwise((before, after) => new
{
    AddedToList = after.Except(before),
    RemovedFromList = before.Except(after)
})
.Publish(p =>
{
    var additions = p.SelectMany(i => i.AddedToList);
    var removals = p.SelectMany(i => i.RemovedFromList);
    return
        additions
        .Select(add =>
            add
            .Delete
            .Select(_ => add)
            .TakeUntil(removals.Where(rem => rem == add)))
        .Merge();
}).Subscribe(i =>
{
    // process the delete request on i
    // at the end, submit the modified array to _items
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up building. It works pretty well for me. The first part is a general purpose class to calculate and report on the differences between two sets.

```
public class SetComparison<T>
{
    private Lazy<IImmutableSet<T>> _added;
    private Lazy<IImmutableSet<T>> _removed;
    private Lazy<IImmutableSet<T>> _intersection;

    public SetComparison(IEnumerable<T> previous, IEnumerable<T> current)
    {
        if (previous == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(previous));
        if (current == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(current));
        Previous = previous.ToImmutableHashSet();
        Current = current.ToImmutableHashSet();
        _added = new Lazy<IImmutableSet<T>>(() => Current.Except(Previous));
        _removed = new Lazy<IImmutableSet<T>>(() => Previous.Except(Current));
        _intersection = new Lazy<IImmutableSet<T>>(() => Current.Intersect(Previous));
    }

    public IImmutableSet<T> Previous { get; }
    public IImmutableSet<T> Current { get; }
    public IImmutableSet<T> Added => _added.Value;
    public IImmutableSet<T> Removed => _removed.Value;
    public IImmutableSet<T> Intersection => _intersection.Value;
}
```

And this is a general purpose operator like the F# Pairwise to take a sequence and turn it into a series of overlapping pairs of items.

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Pairwise<TSource, TResult>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> resultSelector) =>
    source.Scan(
        (default(TSource), default(TSource)),
        (pair, current) => (pair.Item2, current))
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(p => resultSelector(p.Item1, p.Item2));
```

And this now does a pairwise of two sets.

```
public static IObservable<SetComparison<T>> PairwiseSetComparison<T, TCollection>(this IObservable<TCollection> source) where TCollection : IEnumerable<T> =>
    source
    .Pairwise((a, b) => new SetComparison<T>(a, b));


public static IObservable<SetComparison<T>> PairwiseSetComparison<T>(this IObservable<ImmutableArray<T>> source) =>
    source.Pairwise((a, b) => new SetComparison<T>(a, b));
```

And finally this, to

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Merge<TResult, T>(this IObservable<SetComparison<T>> source, Func<T, IObservable<TResult>> result) =>
    source
    .Publish(s =>
    {
        var additions = s.SelectMany(i => i.Added);
        var removals = s.SelectMany(i => i.Removed);
        return
            additions
            .Select(add => result(add).TakeUntil(removals.Where(rem => rem.Equals(add))))
            .Merge();
    });
```

So now when I want to subscribe to observables that are only in the current set, I do something like this...

```
_items
.PairwiseSetComparison()
.Merge(i => i.Delete.Select(_ => i))
.Subscribe(i=> /* user clicked Delete on item i */)
```

Another way to do all this is to have the Delete ICommand on each item in the list actually run some delegate when the user invokes it. That way I don't have to actually subscribe to when the command is invoked. I prefer to keep the items in my list completely unaware of their surroundings, though.